# How to alidate a form in php then submit it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I am using php to validate my form before submitting, I want to post to index.php but I have two problems:

1. If I do form action to `$_SERVER` it will validate the form without going to index.php and trigger the code there:

   ```
   <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" id="contact"  name="contact" method="post"
   ```

   and

   ```
   if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
       if (empty($_POST["fname"])) {
           $nameErr = "Name is required";
           $hasError = true; 
       } else {
           $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
       }
   }
   ```
2. If I do `action= index.php` it submits the form without validating:

   ```
   <form id="contact" action="index.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" >
   ```

So I want to validate the form then submit. any suggestions?

Comment: If you want to validate the form data before submitting it back to a PHP script you will need to learn javascript

Comment: i would suggest you validate the form in client side after validation you can send an ajax request to process server side data.

Comment: Validate client side, but remember to never trust client side data.  You should also validate on the server as well.

Comment: Why don’t you place your validation code in the script that the data gets submitted to in the first place?

Comment: Maybe all you need to know is how to use `header('Location xxx.php');` so you can get your PHP validation script to redirect to whatever the next page in your flow is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several hints for you.

1. Don't use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`. Use `action=""` instead.
2. Don't use JavaScript to validate unless you have really complex validation requirements.

   ```
   <input type="text" name="fname" required />
   <input type="email" />
   <input type="number" min="0" max="99" />
   ```

   These are just some examples of what you can do instead, and all of these will prevent the form from submitting if the validation doesn't pass, *even when the browser's JavaScript is disabled*.
3. Even if you have validation in the browser (whether it's JavaScript or HTML5 forms), you ***must*** validate the input on the server too. Remember, users can send you whatever they want if they're determined, and you can only trust your server.

Comment: So now I removed $_SERVER[ 'PHP_SELF'] and used action="" and I didn't add any action because as I did before if I put index.php it will submit the form without validating. now it validate but it won't submit to index.php